# Software that can generate a nested box diagram from data

Tags: diagram

I'm looking for a tool that can automatically generate a nested diagram from a data set.

E.g.

```
Outer box 1; inner box 1
Outer box 1; inner box 2
Outer box 2; inner box 3
Outer box 2; inner box 4
```

Would create 6 boxes in total 4 nested internally and 2 outer boxes

[image]